# Mongo doesn't connect

Tags: mongodb

I´ve just installed mongodb for windows. But I can´t connect from the mongoose module. I created the data folder in c, and the bd folder inside it. When running mongod I don´t get the "listening to 127.0.0.1 on port 127017" message. I uninstalled mongo and reinstalled it but nothing change. I´ll be grateful if anybody can help me with this trouble. Thank you!

This is the screen I get when running mongod
[image: This is the screen I get when running mongod]

Comment: Server is up & running. Include the command issued for connecting. Typing `mongo` on a terminal an pressing Enter should be enough though.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks so much.  Solved